# full calendar event description

Tags: javascript, python, fullcalendar, flask

El día de hoy estoy trabajando con Full calendar, hice una pequeña ventana modal para que cuando le de clic a un evento, me muestre sus diferentes datos, aquí está mi código JavaScript para el calendario:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            // defaultDate: '2017-09-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            selectable: true,
            events: {
                url: 'data',
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error")
                }
            },


                eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
                //alert("nombre del evento" + event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS") );
                //$('#myModalLabel').html(event.title);
                $('#ModalTitle').html(event.title);    
                $('#start').html(event.start.format("YYYY-DD-MM h\ hh:mm:ss") );
                $('#Modalevent').modal('show');
            },
        });

    });
```

Con ello obtengo el siguiente calendario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al presionar un evento obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, ahora mi problema es que, quiero obtener el DATE dentro de un `input` y no en un `label`, pero cuando lo coloco y hago exactamente lo mismo que con el `label`, no me muestra la fecha, me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero obtenerlo en un input, ya que trabajo con python y mandaré esos datos mediante el método request a python, adjunto un ejemplo de otra ventana modal que ya hice :

```
@app.route('/send', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def send():  
       if request.method == 'POST':


        bay= request.form['Bay']
        rack= request.form['Rack']
        status= request.form['Status']
        user= request.form['User']
        comment= request.form['Comment']
        hostname= request.form['Hostname']
        hostname = str(hostname)
```

pero para esto, necesito tener el dato en el input, alguien sabe como puedo hacer que aparezca en el input correctamente? o porque no me aparece.
Adjunto el código html:

MUESTRA CON LABEL:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modalevent">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-inverse">
                <h3 class="modal-title text-center" id="ModalTitle">
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h3 class="text-center"> DATE</h3>
```

```
                    **<h4 class="text-center" id="start"  name="date"> DATE: </h1>**
                        <br>
                        <h3 class="text-center"> CATEGORY</h3>
                        <select class="form-control" name="category">

                          <option>Work</option>
                          <option>Schedule_Downtime</option>              
                          <option>Non_Schedule_Downtime</option>           
                          <option>Overtime</option>                                            

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

MUESTRA CON INPUT:

```
<!-- Ventana modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="Modalevent">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-inverse">
                    <h3 class="modal-title text-center" id="ModalTitle">
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h3 class="text-center"> DATE</h3>
                        **<input class="form-control" name"start">**
                            <br>
                            <h3 class="text-center"> CATEGORY</h3>
                            <select class="form-control" name="category">

                              <option>Work</option>
                              <option>Schedule_Downtime</option>              
                              <option>Non_Schedule_Downtime</option>           
                              <option>Overtime</option>                                            

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Cual es la línea de código exacta donde asignas el valor al label y cual donde lo haces al input?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez ya he editado la pregunta y he colocado entre ** las líneas indicadas.

Comment: Agregale a tu input un `id="start"` y en tu js cambias esta línea `$('#start').html(event.start.format("YYYY-DD-MM h\ hh:mm:ss") );` por esta `$('#start').val(event.start.format("YYYY-DD-MM h\ hh:mm:ss") );` si te funciona me dices para publicarlo como respuesta y explicarte cual era el error.

Comment: @CamiloVasquez, te agradezo muchisimo, funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: Ok te publico como respuesta y te explico !

Comment: De acuerdo, muchisimas gracias!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tu estabas haciendo era simplemente cambiar la estructura HTML, reemplazar un `<h4>` por un `<input>` sin mirar en el js como era que se le estaba asignando el contenido a ese `<h4>`.

1. Al agregar el `<input>` debías agregarle también el id que tenia el `<h4>`, es decir `id="start"`
2. Como el elemento que se agregó nuevo es un elemento de entrada de texto entonces no se le asigna contenido si no que se le asigna un valor, es decir no se debe usar `.html()` si no que se debe usar `.val()` quedando el código así:

   ```
   $('#start').val(event.start.format("YYYY-DD-MM h\ hh:mm:ss") );
   ```

Comment: Muy bien explicado, muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo, excelente respuesta.

Comment: @Roger me alegra que te haya servido y haberme hecho entender, te invito a que marques la respuesta como aceptada para que los desarrolladores futuros sepan que fue una solución correcta, también deberías de hacerte el [tour] es muy importante saber el funcionamiento básico del sitio.